# MAC OSX: Is it possible to create an instance and use a Internet Plugin directly

Tags: macos, cocoa, plugins, npapi, osx-yosemite

I am new to Max OSX Plugin thing. I saw a few plugins in "/Library/Internet Plug-ins" directory on my Mac 10.10 and was wondering if it is possible to use any of these directly? By directly I mean if I can load and create an instance of a class inside these plug-ins and use in my Cocoa OSX application.

The plug-in that I want to use is NPAPI based. Is it possible to load this plug-in directly (outside of Browser) and use as a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own NPAPI host, and if it does a good enough job of implementing the NPAPI architecture then you would be able to load plugins with it.

It's not going to be a trivial undertaking, however.